# issue with appending the element with $()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I am trying to append the element the following way but is not working...
e.d[0].UserName does have value.. :)

```
                 success: function(e){
       console.log(e);
       console.log(e.d[0].UserName);
       var position2= $("#searchtextbox").position();
       $('<div/>',
       {
         id:'generatedsearchdiv1', 
         css:{
              position:absolute,
              left:position2.left, 
              top:position2.top+20
              },
         text:e.d[0].UserName
         }).appendTo('#searchArea');

       }
```

Comment: You may want to put the css part in proper quotations, too.

Comment: first&nbsp;last names

Comment: Yes it exists and the #generatedsearchdiv1 is not there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't put quotation marks around 'absolute' (`position:'absolute'`) so the script is trying to find a variable named 'absolute'.

Comment: @Spirals Whirls, see console =)